# Sync OneTab tabs on Chrome across different PC's

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I'm using the OneTab extension for Chrome on all of my PC's and I'm looking for a solution/workaround to sync all the tabs automatically across my computers. OneTab doesn't provide any sync capability yet, I even emailed them to ask but I got no answer.

So far, I'm using the import/export feature but I don't like this method as it adds more frustration to the whole experience.

Any possible solution to "fix" this? I know I'm not the only one out there with the same request.

Comment: We don't do product recomendations here at Superuser.  Xmarks supports this sort of functionality though.

Comment: I'm not looking for a product recommendation, just a workaround of how I can solve this problem. Couldn't find anything on google and thought that some Superusers might already fix that somehow. :)

Comment: There isn't a non-software work around for this problem.  The extension you have selected to use does not support what you want, so a different extension, is required to do it.

Comment: From OneTab team : "March 2015 Update: We're currently working on new features including an option for multi-PC cloud sync."

Comment: Thanks @politicus do you know when this feature will be released?

Comment: It's 2020 and they are still very very far away from implementing it :-x

Answer (score 10):

Maybe to complete Anshuman's answer, in *OneTab* tab you can share your tabs as a webpage. If you sync your bookmarks, you can bookmark that page and access it from any device.

1. Go to *OneTab* tab and *Share all as web page*
2. Bookmark that page

That's it ! Very simple. Works with any browser that allows tab sync.

If you want to merge bookmarks from other devices, you load all the tabs in your browser from OneTab and re-send them to OneTab with new tabs.

Comment: But the page won't update whenever you add new tabs to onetab...

Comment: do you know what is the duration of that webpage? will it stay there "for life" or will it expire soon after creation?

Comment: Alternatively, after *Share all as web page*, the links can be imported as Chrome bookmarks. First save the OneTab shared tabs page as html and then import using Chrome Bookmark Manager. It will create an 'Imported' folder containing the links.

Answer (score 9):

Your question was legitimate. Find the local storage for your chrome extension and share that folder via dropbox or other cloud sync solution. Do the same thing on your other PCs... Be careful, your different One Tab bookmarks won't merge.. So make sure to take what you want from the secondary PCs first, and then remove the One Tab files on them, before syncing with your main PC.. Once you've done this, you can save One Tab's on any PC and they will all sync.

Comment: For fellow Linux users: on my system this file is located at `/home/me/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/chrome-extension_XXX_0.localstorage` and `...-journal`

Comment: Tying into @JackSenechal's comment, on Windows, it would be located in `/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Storage/`. Additionally, the OneTab website (https://www.one-tab.com/) makes mention as of October 2015 that they are working on their own syncing solution.

Comment: I think the exactly name of the storage is `chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can easily share one tab as url(see image above) or search for cloud based tab sync solutions. Which I think is TabCloud.

Comment: The share as web page feature appears to provide a static one-way data dump, not a dynamic sync across multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Toby](https://www.gettoby.com/blog/post/toby-is-getting-new-features) will be a good choose.

Toby, in simple terms, it’s a better tab manager. It’s a better way to manage information, context switching, shared information, and productive focus.

also, it can sync your tabs.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesnt allow saving multiple tabs at once, which is my main use of OneTab. see my answer for my strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fix / workaround:

- share as webpage, as above
- go to History
- open saved OneTab webpage in a new tab
- all saved (webpage) tabs are now available

Comment: all other suggested fixes are geek-tech-babble.  Easy Breezy!

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy fix, just download http://www.zibity.com/macdropany.html and you're set to go:

1. Go to the following folder on your computer: /Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage
2. Sync the 'Local Storage' folder using the macdropany prog
3. Set the dropbox location
4. That's it, the macdropany will sync the 'local storage' folder to your dropbox, inside the 'local storage' you'll find two files that are related to onetab:

   - chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage-journal
   - chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage

Whenever you'll need to restore onetab, just go to your dropbox folder open the synced folder and use dropbox 30 days back of backup files.

Answer (score 0):

My new goto tool is TabSessionManager. It will sync your tabs automatically periodically to your Google account, and works on both Firefox and Chrome. 
https://tab-session-manager.sienori.com/

I have used OneTab import/export when migrating, because BetterOneTab's sync is no longer supported. Toby doesnt allow saving of multiple tabs at once. OneTabPlus doenst have syncing and the backup function may be difficult after crashing because of the merged extensions storage in Firefox. Similar problems with TidyTab. [save tabs to bookmark folder extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-tabs-to-bookmark-folder/) is very useful.

I'm no longer going to use OneTab because of the [difficulty of manually restoring](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1261474) from a file in Firefox. The extension storage file has been converted to a Firefox db file. Supposedly it can [still be done](https://superuser.com/a/1645274/388883) in Chrome. This problem is so bad, it looks like a [paid extension](https://workona.com/blog/one-tab-extension-lost-all-tabs/) has cropped up.

Using TSM above in combination with the [TabMover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mover/) Firefox extension is working, as it moves multiple tabs to a window, and I can close it to save memory. Then reopen it to add more tabs, and I dont think the other tabs are loaded. If they are there are extensions or even FF prefs to do that. Chrome has a move to specific window function by default.

Answer (score -2):

On your old laptop:
- Right click on the OneTab icon > Display OneTab
- On the new tab that opens, with all OneTab links: on top-right area click on Export / Import URLs
- Copy all links from Export url field
- Email them to yourself

On your new laptop:
- Open the email and copy the links
- Retake the steps above
- Paste all the links in the field Import URSs

That is all.

PS:
On the OneTab page, on top-right area there are several useful url's:
Bring all tabs into OneTab
Share all as web page
Export / Import URLs
Options
New! Features / Help
About / Feedback