# Where is my data for Chrome extension 'OneTab'?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, google-chrome-extensions

[OneTab](https://www.one-tab.com/) is my favorite Chrome extension. I regularly back up OneTab data in Windows 7 following this blog post:

*[OneTab: Finding where your tabs are stored](http://elearningkaizen.blogspot.kr/2017/03/onetab-finding-where-your-tabs-are.html)*

But today, I can't find OneTab data in that path.

Is anything updated in Chrome or OneTab? If so, *where* is the OneTab data?

Comment: I've moved to a different tool because Firefox has converted the extension data storage to a db file.. https://superuser.com/a/1714380/388883

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the latest place where the files are located:

`C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall`

Answer (score 6):

Your OneTab data can be found at `C:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Storage/leveldb`. Just replace `<Username>` with your user's username.

I also created a Python script to automatically back up your OneTab data.

https://github.com/itsjoshthedeveloper/backupOneTab

More information found in the link above.

Answer (score 4):

On ([Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint)) Linux, the path to the OneTab data folder appears to be:

```
/home/<user>/.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall
```

or

```
/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Extension Settings/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall
```

Copying this folder from Chromium to Chrome (after Chromium access to [the Chrome sync API was recently disabled](https://superuser.com/a/1620602/468354)) adds all the titles and options associated with OneTab links.

Comment: this is an extremely dangerous answer. I glanced in here, relevant data seemed to be in `00003.log`. I copied that file over, while making the equivalent file in my new install named `00003.log.bak` as a sibling file. When I then opened chrome, I did indeed have my onetab... but lost all my current tabs. I saved a onetab export, figuring I'd go grab the old file and get it back... and chrome or onetab had deleted my .bak file. tabs gone forever. :/

Comment: @KyleBaker, that stinks. When I performed the copy, I had already installed OneTab on Chrome and so I copied that folder from Chromium settings to Chrome settings without altering Chromium in any way. There was no data loss for me since I was just seeing if Chrome would recognize the OneTab data from Chromium. Perhaps this has changed? Copy-paste was always a work-around for a feature missing from OneTab (that is, Titles included in the export function). I didn't try to edit any file inside the settings folder, since Chrome has a habit of rewriting data and I had no idea what format it was.

Comment: yeah, was my girlfriend's computer. she'd been using the new install for a while, suddenly wanted her old onetab stuff. was pretty frustrating for her, she lost hours of research.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the path has changed since then.

Now, the localstorage file resides in *~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Default/Local Storage* (on Mac, but it's easy to guess the equivalent on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, the location is now in a database file located in your users folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Local Storage/leveldb/ files here...
```

I am not sure if all the files here are dedicated to OneTab, but restoring the whole folder worked for me.
You may need to check for other *Profile* folders, or perhaps the default instead of my "Profile 1" folder.
A shortcut to the folder, open terminal and execute the command:

```
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 1/Local\ Storage/leveldb/
```

Answer (score 1):

- Mac OSX Ventura 13.0.1
- Chrome 109.0.5414.87

I found OneTab's `.ldb` files located at:

```
~Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Extension Settings/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall
```

Comment: Same answer has been proposed several times before.

Comment: @Toto different path.  most recently located in extension settings, not profile settings, and since .ldb files are not the easiest to parse, this information would have saved me 30 mins.