# Cannot find the Chromium Sync feature anymore

Tags: linux, chromium, google-sync, google-accounts, fedora-33

I started up the Chromium browser and noticed that my Google User Profile picture was gone from the top right corner. I was all signed in previously on this browser and it was completely synced with my Google account. I used to sign into Chromium before normally.

[Image: Profile widget saying "not signed in"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYgve.png)

I began looking for solutions, and two sources explained you just need to turn on "Allow Chromium sign-in" in the settings. I checked that, it was enabled, still no way of getting the sign-in, or syncing back.

[Image: Settings Page with missing Google Sync or sign-in forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTRiY.png)

```
Installed Packages
Name         : chromium
Version      : 88.0.4324.96
Release      : 1.fc33
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 320 M
Source       : chromium-88.0.4324.96-1.fc33.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : A WebKit (Blink) powered web browser
URL          : http://www.chromium.org/Home
License      : BSD and LGPLv2+ and ASL 2.0 and IJG and MIT and GPLv2+ and ISC and OpenSSL and (MPLv1.1 or GPLv2 or LGPLv2)
Description  : Chromium is an open-source web browser, powered by WebKit (Blink).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fedora no longer supports use of Googles private APIs in Chromium (only officially branded Chrome). The change occurred this weekend.
See more info here: https://www.zdnet.com/article/fedora-preemptively-turns-off-chromium-usage-of-private-google-sync-apis/

By March 15th of 2021 google intends to prevent all non-google versions of Chromium from accessing these APIs. Google claims their use was unintentionally allowed up until now, and a recent audit found that they were in fact available. more info here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/chromium-sync-google-api-removed

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now it makes sense to me. For the time being, I have removed Chromium with _dnf remove_, and reinstalled it using _snap install_ (https://snapcraft.io/chromium). The *snap* version still features the Google sign-in to Sync, giving me a chance to sort out all my bookmarks and export them. I will take these to Mozilla Firefox perhaps. Cheers!